# What happens to the writes when the Azure Table Storage primary region fails?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I am using Azure Table Storage. I am using RA-GRS replication model. I would like to know what happens in the case of a failure to the primary region, will I be able to write to a secondary region?

Comment: Please note that RA-GRS is "Read Access - Geo Redundant Storage". You don't have write access to secondary per its name. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Secondaries are read-only, by design. If there's a catastrophic situation within a region, your secondary storage account could be shifted to primary, but 1) that's outside your control and 2) a very rare exception (e.g. never happened before, as far as I know).

If you absolutely need to maintain ability to write, then it would be up to you to have an alternative storage account with primary region being different from your main storage account's region.

Comment: Also a good approach is wrap your code with a retry pattern / transient fault handler.

Comment: ```CloudTableClient = CloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();``` Here CloudTableClienthas a property called CloudTableClient.BaseUri.AbsoluteUri will that change to secondary in the event of a failure?