# Does CloudTableClient.BaseUri.AbsoluteUri value changes when Azure Table Storage Primary region fails?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I know that `CloudTableClient.BaseUri.AbsoluteUri` returns a string value which represents the **primary endpoint**. But, in a case of failure does this value update to the **secondary endpoint**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.cloudtableclient.baseuri.aspx), CloudTableClient.BaseUri will get the base URI for the table service client at the primary location as you mentioned.

As David Makogon mentioned in your another [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42497854/what-happens-to-the-writes-when-the-azure-table-storage-primary-region-fails), it is a very rare expection and out of our control. Secondary storage account will be shifted to primary. When use CloudTableClient.BaseUri we will still get the primary endpoint. For more infomation, please refer to  [what to expect if a Storage failover occurs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-disaster-recovery-guidance#what-to-expect-if-a-storage-failover-occurs). There is some snippet from the article.

> Your existing storage service endpoints for blobs, tables, queues, and files will remain the same after the failover; the DNS entry will need to be updated to switch from the primary region to the secondary region.